# MySQL Operand should contain 1 column(s) INSERT

Tags: mysql

**Order Table**

```
id
orderlinesid
productvaritiesid
```

**orderlines Table**

```
orderlinesid
productvaritiesid(fk)
```

I am trying to do an insert into an `Order` table. My query returns the following exception `"Operand should contain 1 column(s)"`. By looking at the question on SO I can see only one column in the sub query is returned.

My Question is how do I go about it trying to achieve this?

```
INSERT INTO refund (refund.orderlinesid, refund.productvaritiesid) VALUES
 ((select orderlines.orderlinesid, orderlines.product_varities_id from orderlines where orderlines.order_id = 54 AND orderlines.product_varities_id = 3));
```

Comment: No parenthesis, no VALUES, i.e. `INSERT INTO (x,y,z) SELECT x,y,z FROM ...`. The `VALUES` syntax is used for single row inserts from input data, whereas the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` is used to copy rows from another query.

Comment: That works, but can you explain why this syntax is correct?@StuartLC

Comment: @Harry The MySQL docs have some explanation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect syntax on your code,
the values refers to specific case

```
INSERT INTO refund
   (refund.orderlinesid, refund.productvaritiesid)
select orderlines.orderlinesid, orderlines.product_varities_id
from orderlines
where orderlines.order_id = 54 AND orderlines.product_varities_id = 3;
```